# How do I make a app match a provisioning profile on xcode?

Tags: xcode

I am having a heck of a time trying to get this to work.  At this point, I am only trying to create little test apps in xcode and "build and run" them on xcode-not on my phone.

I have a provisioning profile for my phone in the xcode organizer, but that is the only one I have.

Do I also need a separate provisioning profile for the desktop sdk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need provisioning profiles for developing on iphone simulator.

If you also want to develop on your device, first register the device when creating the provisioning profile, then upload the provisioning profile to your device.

Apple's documentation is pretty clear and easy to follow on this issue.

Good luck.

Edit: 1- You need provisioning for developing on the device, thats why it gives you a provisioning error when you try running with  -iphone device xxx.

2-The blank white screen on the simulator has nothing to do with provisioning, you succeded to run your code on the simulator, but either your code does nothing or you did not link your uiwindow to your views

3-Base sdk defines that dropdown menu on the topleft. If you select iphone 3.1.2 as base sdk in project settings, you can only see simulator/device 3.1.2 on the dropdown menu, if you select 2.0 as your base sdk you will see device/simulator 2.0,2.1,2.2.1,3.0,3.1.2,... on the dropdown menu. Since you selected 3.1.2 as base sdk you don't see earlier versions on the dropdown menu.

Comment: I have not had an easy time with the documentation at all.  It is verbose, but very very difficult for me to grasp.

Comment: I only installed the SDK a couple weeks ago-which is the newer version.  I do not see the option to select 2.0 as my base SDK.  Is this a separate install?

Comment: Edit:OK.  I see what you are saying-I changed the settings there.  I don't know why this is so counter-intuitive to me...it's my xp mindset :-D

Comment: @Joel:  It seems that Apple does not make it easy to use 2.0 for your base after you install 3.x.  I have been trying this for a while, but they remove all older SDKs when they release the new one it seems.

Comment: @Jeff-Read #3 above for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need provisioning profiles to run an app in the simulator, if that's what you mean. Just make sure you're Build-and-Go-ing for a simulator - iPhone Simulator 3.0, say - and you should be good to go.

Comment: When i try and build and run with the "iPhone Device 3.1.2 (Base SDK)" I get the provisioning error.

When I try and build and run with "iPhone Simulator 3.1.2" I get a "succeeded" but, I just get a blank white screen on the simulator...

Comment: Well-it is certainly weird.  I don't have the dropdown options for different iphone builds in xcode (should i?) but on the simulator, I could change versions.  I changed to 3.0 and the app didn't work, but then changing back to 3.1.2, the app did show up on the screen.  So what is the "iPhone Device Base SDK" then, and why do I get the prodisioning error there?

Comment: I have the XCode iPhone SDK. I don't know if that's a special version of XCode or not. The main project window though has a dropdown on the top left letting me choose which SDK I want to use to build the app: Use Base SDK, ..., iPhone Device 3.0, ..., iPhone Simulator 3.1, ...

Comment: OK-I figured that out-I changed the settings in project settings, and now I see earlier versions available.  Cool.  Thanks!